# Agrupar resultado de un for

Tags: javascript

Quiero agrupar los resultados que obtengo de un for por un campo que se repite tantas veces como resultados hay, la verdad es que no tengo muy claro como hacer un segundo for:

```
var records = document.getElementById('INFO');
records.innerHTML = '';
var html = '';
for (i=0; i<feature.length; i++){('')
    records.innerHTML += '<h2>' + feature[i].get('codigo') + '</h2>';
    if(feature[i].get('arte') !=null){
        records.innerHTML += '<h2>' + feature[i].get('arte') + '</h2>';
    }else{
        records.innerHTML += '';
    }
    if(feature[i].get('fecha_actividad') !=null){
        records.innerHTML += '<h2>' + feature[i].get('fecha_actividad') + '</h2>';
    }else{
        records.innerHTML += '';
    }
}
```

Supongamos que obtengo 3 resultados, de esos 3 resultados, por ejemplo, 2 tienen el mismo código, con este ciclo for se escriben secuencialmente uno tras otros hasta completar la salida de los 3. Lo que quiero es agrupar los que tienen el mismo código y muestre el resto de los registros y después ponga los siguientes códigos con el resto de registros. (el formato no sería ese claro)

| cod: 64 |
| --- |
| especialidad: baile - fecha:29/10/2020 |
| especialidad:canto - fecha:30/10/2020 |

| cod:65 |
| --- |
| especialidad: baile - fecha:29/10/2020 |

gracias!

Comment: La verdad que no se entiende nada la situación ni el problema.

Comment: Hola, no logro entender qué es lo que quieres hacer. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] por si te sirve para estructurar tu pregunta. Danos contexto para que sea mas facil ayudarte

Comment: Lo he resuelto de otra manera, he cambiado el código para que en lugar de listar todos los elementos de una vez en cada vuelta del bucle, se pregunte si el elemento es diferente y solamente se añade si es distinto al anterior.